# iOS 8 AVAudioTime has functions missing?

Tags: ios, core-audio

AVAudioTime documentation in Apple has the following functions that I can't get to work

```
class func hostTimeForSeconds(_ seconds: NSTimeInterval) -> UInt64
```

if I do

```
var timeDiff = AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time())
var time: NSTimeInterval = 1000        
timeDiff.hostTimeForSeconds(time)
```

I get

```
'AVAudioTime' does not have a member named 'hostTimeForSeconds'
```

Am I missing something? or this is a bug?

Thx.

Reference:
[AVAudioTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/AVAudioTime_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVAudioTime/secondsForHostTime:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a class method.

```
AVAudioTime.hostTimeForSeconds(time)
```

Comment: Awesome! I should just added that I'm a beginner in swift!

Comment: Everyone is a beginner in Swift. :)